# Inspecting a TLS Certificate to determine RSA Key Usage restrictions

Tags: cryptography, encryption, tls, certificates, certificate-authority

With regard to [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/what-ciphers-should-i-used-in-my-web-server-after-i-configure-my-ssl-certificate/7621#7621), I have a question about Key Usage in an SSL certificate.

> Most SSL server certificates have a RSA key which is not restricted
>   through a Key Usage extension, so you can use both "RSA" and "DHE_RSA"
>   key types.

- How do I determine if my certificate has a key usage restriction?
- Do all SSL Keys have an RSA key?
- Is there only one key usage to look out for, or are there others?

Where should I learn more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should learn to use the "openssl" command-line tool (available for Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, etc.).

Type on the command line: (where mycert is your certificate)

```
openssl x509 -text -in mycert
```

This decodes all the fields in the certificate, and will list any restrictions.

No, it doesn't have to be RSA. You can select Diffie-Helmman instead when you create your certificate.

There are a wide variety of certificate uses. For example, you might want a certificate that can sign other certificates for the domain, so that you don't need to buy individual certificates from a CA, but can create them yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Not all certificates use RSA, but most do. A few months ago, I scanned a lot of random IP addresses to find SSL servers, and out of 10147 certificate chains (from 16027 servers -- there is considerable chain reuse), only 9 of them used anything else than RSA (6 with DSA keys, 3 with GOST keys; no Diffie-Hellman, no ECDSA). This is more than market dominance; RSA has an almost monopoly on cryptographic algorithms for SSL servers.

<sup>(I should write a Web page somewhere with all the stats.)</sup>

Apart from the `Key Usage` extension, a few other extensions can be relevant; see [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6844/how-are-possible-uses-for-x-509-ssl-certificates-denoted/40480#40480) for details.